# In Dungeon Petz, what is the optimal round to pick the "Inviting new imps" action space?

Tags: dungeon-petz

What is the optimal round to pick the "Inviting new imps" action space in a 2-, 3- and 4-player game, respectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you want to do this action exactly twice a game.

- First time early, it depends on your turn order and on your opponents move. Ideally it would be around second or third round, so that you get more then one new imp, but it is not too late in the game.
- Second time is a trade-off between penalty from not getting all your imps and have them used more times, I would go for them in round 4. Make sure to get at least 2 new imps.

Consider going for imps additional time in last round if your opponents have lots of imps away to prevent opponents from getting them and so that they get penalty.